# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show Couldn't find Article with 'id'=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I am getting an error when I got into articles/edit.

I am getting this error:
[image]

when I should be getting this error:

[image]

my code:

articles_controller:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @article = Article.new 
  end

  def edit 
   @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end 

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)
    if @article.save
      flash[:notice] = "Article was submitted succsefully"
      redirect_to (@article)
    else
      render :new
    end 
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end 

  private 
  def article_params 
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :description)
  end
end
```

my edit.html.erb :

```
<h1>Edit the existing article</h1>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
<h2>The following errors are informing you that if you don't do these then 
your articles will not be edited</h2>
  <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li> <%= msg %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field:title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description  %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

my new.html.erb :

```
<h1>Create an article</h1>
<% if @article.errors.any? %>
<h2>The following errors are informing you that if you don't do these then 
your articles will not be created</h2>
  <ul>
    <% @article.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li> <%= msg %> </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
<%= form_for @article do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field:title %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :description  %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

my routes.rb:

```
resources :articles
root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'
```

Ask Me For More Files If It Helps

Comment: What query params are you using. can you reply with the URL

Comment: Danil Speransky here it is :                                 
    
resources :articles

root 'pages#home'
get 'about', to: 'pages#about'

Comment: Can you show the link you click to go to your 'edit' view?

Comment: https://my-app-shashiyerra.c9users.io/articles/edit

Comment: I think that is what you are talking about if not please clarify.. I am VERY new to programming

Comment: I think what @EJ2015 means is which link did you _click_ to get there. Showing the HTML of that link is best.

Comment: okay but I have it in my question up there in my edit.html.erb

Comment: Which is the link you click before you get to that error page? The error is probably there.

Comment: I did not click any link I just changed to articles/edit

Comment: You should make sure to add any code others ask for to the question instead of the comments...these aren't always visible or permanent and are harder to read (I've added the routes to the question for you). Also, when possible, you should add errors as text instead of images. Those images are blurry and I can't read either to see what you're actually talking about

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then that's the cause of the error. 'edit' page requires an id param otherwise. as in your controller:

```
def edit 
 @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

It needs `params[:id]`

So you need to use `/articles/id/edit` (replace id with your actual id)

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: Think of it as you are not supposed to edit all articles at the same time. You can only edit one Article at a time, so if you have an Article in the database with `id=5`, then going to the link `/articles/5/edit` will take you to the view where you can edit that particular Article. Does the make sense?

Answer (score 2):

`resources :articles` will create a `edit_article_path` helper that you should use to link to the edit action:

```
<%= link_to("Edit article", edit_article_path(@article)) %>
```

This will create the correct path with a `:id` segment:

```
      Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                  Controller#Action
    articles GET    /articles(.:format)          articles#index
             POST   /articles(.:format)          articles#create
 new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      articles#new
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) articles#edit
     article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#show
             PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#update
             DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      articles#destroy
```

Comment: Additionally instead of repeating the form create a `articles/_form.html.erb` partial and include it in your new and edit views with `<%= render partial: 'form' %>`. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials

Comment: And the correct and polite way to say it is: `The following errors prevented the article from being <%= @article.new_record? ? "created" : "updated" %>`.